# Some custom UITableViewCells are not rendering

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom cell UITableViewCell, sometimes when the tableview loads, I am getting missing cells (cells where the content view is not rendering at all.  I get this behavior fairly consistently when I use reloadRowsAtIndexPath (when a custom object the cell is using is updated for example).  If I call reloadData on the tableview, I usually don't get this behavior.

Here is what it looks like when view debugging:
[image: Content View is missing]

Here is the cell under that (which rendered fine):
[image: ContentView rendered]

My initialization of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath is the usual pattern:

Edit - entire cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reuseIdentifier = "WorkOrderListCell"
    let cell:WorkOrderListCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier) as! WorkOrderListCell
```

If I scroll the tableview so that the cell which did not render is off screen, and then scroll back, the cell will render.

I have also ensured that I am on the main queue by wrapping my reloadRowsAtIndexPath in a main queue closure but that doesn't make a difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: On the first screenshot inspector breadcrumbs shows that you've selected a `UITableView` which means the cell didn't render at all or rendered offscreen. You may either have messed up constraints or you modify the cell's frame or bounds offset directly somewhere. Can you post your entire `cellForRowAt:` method? Do you perform a manual height calculation for your cells?

Comment: I do not perform a manual height calculation, the cell height is custom and static.  I think you might be on to something with the constraints being the problem though.    I just noticed I am getting this warning in the log:  Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.  I am not getting any IB warnings or issues with my layout of the cell though.

Comment: I hope this code not get to release

Comment: With your 7 years experience you should know that creating DateFormatter is very expensive and you should create it only once and reuse. But you create DateFormatter in cellForRowAt, facepalm

Comment: @canister_exister - absolutely right.  This is getting cleaned up (and the convenience method as well above that) before production.

Answer (score 4):

Some times there's an issue with table view on first load. So I would suggest reloading tableView data twice. You can use this extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadDataWithAutoSizingCellWorkAround() {
        self.reloadData()
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Which is found in this issue https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/10

Or you can call directly:

```
self.reloadData()
self.setNeedsLayout()
self.layoutIfNeeded()
self.reloadData()
```

Comment: I can call reloadData once and it will render fine.  The issue is that I would rather just reload the cells that I need and not cause a complete reload of the tableview.

Comment: Well you could consider reloading every single row twice then. Or you can use `prepareForReuse(){ super.prepareForReuse() 
 // here you make nil every ui component }`

Comment: I appreciate you for taking the time to help, but that is not a good solution.  :)

Comment: You did however put me on the right track.  Calling setNeedsLayout caused the auto layout engine to spit me out a constraint conflict message.

Comment: Well this issue has been around on iOS for a long time, it's really annoying. Happy to be a little bit of help.

Comment: @LJWilson That's how table views work by default. The UITableView class never loads cells until they're about to appear onscreen, even when you call reloadData.

Comment: @canister_exister - this was not the problem at all.  Found the issue, it was a ambiguous constraint on a view that wasn't showing up in the debugger until I added setNeedsLayout.  Once I saw that and added a breakpoint it became evident what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I had a ambiguous constraint in the content view of the cell.  It only got reported when I added setNeedsLayout in the delegate method to reload the row.  Once I found that, it was easy to find using the a breakpoint and debugging the view.  When I removed the distance constraint that was causing the issue, all the rendering issues went away.  Thanks to @DionizB for putting me on a good path.